# Post Data is not coming

Tags: php, email, postdata

**Update Two**: After doing some testing, I found that it does **not** work when jQuery is loaded in the page. My page relies on jQuery, so what should I do?

**Update**: You can see the problematic page here [here](http://monarctesting.herobo.com/contact/), and the working test page [here](http://monarctesting.herobo.com/contact/testemail.php).

---

I'm making a contact form, and it looks like this

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="../sendemail.php">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span5">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input name="first" type="text" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your First Name">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input name="last" type="text" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your Last Name">
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input name="email" type="text" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your email address">
                </div>
                <div class="span7">
                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" required class="input-block-level" rows="8"></textarea>
                </div>

            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right">Send Message</button>
            <p> </p>

        </form>
```

Nothing too fancy. sendemail.php looks like this

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email sent!'
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['first']." ".$_POST['last'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = "Monarc - Message From ".$name;
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'xxx@xxx.xxx';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

The email comes through, but the postdata isn't coming through in the email. It says (unknown sender) as the sender, and the body looks like this:

> Name:
>
> Email:
>
> Subject: Monarc - Message From
>
> Message:

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Before any actions in sendmail, did you try to `var_dump( $_POST );` to get the data? Is it blank?

Comment: Yes, try print_r($_POST) to see your POST array

Comment: Are you using javascript / jquery / ajax to submit the form?

Comment: @Lepanto No, I'm not.

Comment: Did you check if you are receiving post data using `print_r($_POST); exit;` as suggested by kim?. Add `print_r($_POST); exit;`above `header('Content-type: application/json');` and check if you get all the data posted through your form.

Comment: @Lepanto I found out that jQuery was the issue. I need jQuery for my website, though, so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: What issue you found with jquery?

Comment: @Lepanto I'm not sure at all. It's just causing issues with the contact form

Answer (score 0):

To post the form value you must use input type submit instead of button type

change:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right">Send Message</button>
```

to:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right" value="Send Message">
```

Comment: Nope, still getting the issue. Good idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

supplementary information, this form uses the following javascript file:

> jQuery(function($) {
>
> //Ajax contact  var form = $('.contact-form');      form.submit(function
>   () {          $this = $(this);            $.post($(this).attr('action'),
>   function(data) {
>             $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
>         },'json');      return false;   });
>
> //Goto Top  $('.gototop').click(function(event) {
>   event.preventDefault();        $('html, body').animate({
>              scrollTop: $("body").offset().top       }, 500);   });     //End goto top
>
> });

Searching on another forum I found how to fix this. You only need add the following code in the php file:

```
$headers = "From: mail <$email_from>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" ."\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

and remove "@" of $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body,'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

In "main.js" file your code isn't supplying any data in the .post() method. you need to add $(this).serialize() to get all the form fields/values.

untested but should work -

$.post($(this).attr('action'),$(this).serialize(), function(data) {

Hope that helps resolve the issue

Comment: *This is not a forum*. Answers go in the answers, and questions go in the questions. Ask a new question if the answers on this one don't work for you.

Comment: My intention was to provide more information to help resolve this issue. Because I have the same problem and this topic has not been closed or resolved. if wrong posted my comment, I offer them an apology to you and you can delete my comment. Thank you.