# PHP form post data not being received due to jQuery

Tags: jquery, post, http-post

I have a basic form to send an email. It is sending the email, but not passing the data from the form. Is there something I am missing to allow the data to POST?

HTML form to send email:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send Message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <textarea name="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP code in sendemail.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email sent!'
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = "Example Contact";
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'admin@example.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: ' . $email_from);

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

---

UPDATE:
It looks like there is a problem in js/jquery when the class="contact-form" is included. If I leave it out, the variables are sent.

Here is the jquery code for the form:

```
//contact form
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    return false;
});
```

**Here are some related posts:**

 [PHP Blank Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583385/php-blank-email)

 [Contact form won't submit data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429916/contact-form-wont-submit-data)

 [js deleting submitted form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531435/js-deleting-submitted-form-data)

 [PHP script sending mails but not showing form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696504/php-script-sending-mails-but-not-showing-form-data)

 [Post Data is not coming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193156/post-data-is-not-coming)

Comment: The form by it self (as originaly posted here) works fine, something else is the issue here. JS triggers / events blocking post on click perhaps ?

Comment: Do a var_dump('$_POST'); and see what you get.

Comment: I agree with Ivan, the form works for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling [`jquery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) but you only say where to post to, and what to do when it succeeds. What are you posting? The second parameter needs to be the data you're posting:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
    $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
},'json');
```

Comment: Use your browser's web inspector, watch for the form post going out. Also make sure you've cleared your cache after changing Javascript code.

Comment: Thank you! It was a combination of what you said, plus the ordering of js/form elements on the page. Now I need to find out why its calling the js/mail script twice.